# How do I get multiple references from the autocomplete?

Tags: 8, entities, ajax

I am using the following form element.

```
$form['group']['one'] = array(
    '#type' => 'entity_autocomplete',
    '#title' => t('Tags'),
    '#target_type' => 'user',
);
```

I submit values similar to the following ones.

> user00 (0), user01 (1), user02 (2), user0x (3)

What I receive from the form is the following:

> one = 3

It only picks up the last ID.

How can I get all the references entered in the form element? How does the form element handle the references to not existing entities?

Answer (score 7):

The comma is used to separate multiple references, but looking at the code in [`Name::valueForm()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Plugin%21views%21filter%21Name.php/function/Name%3A%3AvalueForm/8.2.x) I would say the form element needs to use a property more.

```
  $form['value'] = array(
    '#type' => 'entity_autocomplete',
    '#title' => $this->t('Usernames'),
    '#description' => $this->t('Enter a comma separated list of user names.'),
    '#target_type' => 'user',
    '#tags' => TRUE,
    '#default_value' => $default_value,
    '#process_default_value' => $this->isExposed(),
  );
```

Settings `#tags` to `TRUE` makes the the form element accept multiple values.

The format of the values assigned to the form element is evident in [`EntityAutocomplete::validateEntityAutocomplete()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Element%21EntityAutocomplete.php/function/EntityAutocomplete%3A%3AvalidateEntityAutocomplete/8.2.x) (its validation handler), which uses this code.

```
  $input_values = $element['#tags'] ? Tags::explode($element['#value']) : array($element['#value']);

  foreach ($input_values as $input) {
    $match = static::extractEntityIdFromAutocompleteInput($input);
    if ($match === NULL) {
      // Try to get a match from the input string when the user didn't use
      // the autocomplete but filled in a value manually.
      $match = static::matchEntityByTitle($handler, $input, $element, $form_state, !$autocreate);
    }

    if ($match !== NULL) {
      $value[] = array(
        'target_id' => $match,
      );
    }
    elseif ($autocreate) {
      /** @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityReferenceSelection\SelectionWithAutocreateInterface $handler */
      // Auto-create item. See an example of how this is handled in
      // \Drupal\Core\Field\Plugin\Field\FieldType\EntityReferenceItem::presave().
      $value[] = array(
        'entity' => $handler->createNewEntity($element['#target_type'], $element['#autocreate']['bundle'], $input, $element['#autocreate']['uid']),
      );
    }
```

The form element value is an array of item whose `target_id` key is an object of the requested entity.

(From that code, it is also clear that `#tags` makes the form element accepts multiple references separated by commas.)

As for the using reference that aren't found, you can decide what the autocomplete does by setting `#validate_reference`: If you set it to `TRUE`, and `#autocreate` is not set to `TRUE`, the autocomplete will accept only existing references.

Comment: Thank you, the #Tags =True is works, but the valueValidate(); didn't work, it giving me an error: 'There are no entities matching "asd".'

Comment: `Name::valueValidate()` was just to show how multiple entity references are handled. It was not to say "use that method."

Comment: Then is it possible to catch input that is not available in the list (database)?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: shall i have a hint on how to do that? please...

Comment: Set `#validate_reference` to `FALSE`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i just try and read the code to understand, and it goes into: $form_state->setError($element, t('There are no entities matching "%value".', $params)); when i put the new value - so to avoid that code i have to set $element['#autocreate'] = TRUE, but a icant set it as true if it didn't come with: $element['#autocreate']['bundle'], so the question now is: what is $element['#autocreate']['bundle'] and what should i suppose to set in it?

Comment: Bundle, for the User entitity, is simply `'user'`.